# How to verify whether I could create a file in a specific folder or not on Android by C++\C?

Tags: android, c++, c

At my first thought, I should know how to check the permissions of a folder in the Linux system(since the kernel of `Android` is `linux`) by `C` or `C++`.

Since `C++17` is not available for me, so `std::filesystem` could not be used. And I searched on `SO`, I found `access` may be a solution. So I wrote the code snippet below:

```
if (access(folder_path, W_OK | X_OK) == 0) {
     SDK_LOG_ERROR("folder is not writable");
}
```

But it seems not work as expected, I can manually create new files in a specific folder:

```
C:\tools>adb root
adbd is already running as root

C:\tools>adb remount
remount succeeded

C:\tools>adb shell
promotion:/system/etc/some_folder/.../config # ls -lhd .
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4.0K 2022-05-31 21:14 .

promotion:/system/etc/some_folder/.../config # touch a
promotion:/system/etc/some_folder/.../config # touch b

promotion:/system/etc/some_folder/.../config # ls -lh
total 14K
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    0 2022-05-31 21:14 a
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    0 2022-05-31 21:14 b
```

Before running the said code snippet, I call `adb root; adb remount` first, and then I call `whoami` in the terminal, the output is `root`.

But when I run the aforementioned code snippet on `Android`, the program tells me `folder is not writable"`. What a surprise!

Comment: Do you run the code as root?

Comment: @thebusybee I called `adb root` first, which I have posted the related commands in the post. And I just check out that `whoami` returns `root`. Whether running the code as root or not makes a difference?

Comment: Please add such important information to your question by [edit]ing it. Comments are not the place. While you're at it, you could also add the [mre] of your experimental program, and the shell output running it.

Comment: @thebusybee Doing. Sorry, I have not noticed such information is important.

Comment: ["_Upon successful completion, these functions shall return 0._"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)